# Text on the objects in image get disappeared when using imwrite

Tags: matlab

Following is my code:

```
    I=imread('Circle.png');
bw2 = ~im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
bw2=imerode(bw2,SE);
bw2=imerode(bw2,SE);
  L = bwlabel(bw2);

  s = regionprops(L, 'Centroid');
imshow(bw2)

hold on
for k = 1:numel(s)
    c = s(k).Centroid;
    text(c(1), c(2), sprintf('%d', k), ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
        'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');
end
hold off

  OutputFileName = ['./output_images/'  'circle_erode.png'];
   imwrite(mat2gray(bw2),OutputFileName);
```

Whenever I am saving the image, the numbers on the objects get disappeared.I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Please identify the problem.

Comment: You are saving the image data... `text` objects are graphics objects which aren't part of `bw2`. You would need to use `saveas` to save the graphics

Comment: Could you please mention the syntax?

Comment: Try googling "MATLAB save figure"